# Noun meaning "an advertisment that poses as news"

Tags: single-word-requests

This type of ad has always been around, but newpapers and magazines would put the word "advertising" nearby. Some websites are not being so scrupulous. The ads are headlined and written like a news story, but always carefully name the product and supplier somewhere near the end.

Is there a word that designates this kind of ad?

Sample: I was hooked by that _____ selling snake-oil as a cure for cancer.

Comment: "Infomercial" is the term used for a TV ad posing as an "informative" TV show.  The same term is sometimes extended to apply to "fake news" ads in other media.

Comment: If you're uncomfortable saying *infomercial* (which I find does not roll off my tongue), I think "paid announcement" means the same thing.  But we need to look a little farther for the similar phenomenon on the web.

Comment: There are several different meanings depending on to whom you speak, legally they are simply advertisements and must be tagged as such, but advertising companies call them "*commercialised content*" etc.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is an "ISO noun"?

Comment: How about just saying it's _Spam_?  That's what it is, after all. _Clickbait_ also works.

Comment: @Lawrence my guess would be that ISO has been used as stand in for standard(ized).

Comment: @Lawrence - "In search of"

Comment: @HotLicks That fits :) . I'll edit the title to remove the distracting acronym.

Comment: @factsmachine I've taken out the term "ISO" from your question's title because I think it distracts from your actual question. If you consider that ISO is required in the title, please explain what ISO means in your question, and feel free to [edit] your question further or visit the [revisions](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/348317/revisions) page to roll back to your original version.

Comment: @Pete, You are right on spot. I couldn't help chuckle. But, I can't say to someone, "Hey, I was watching some spam on  TV. Apple is coming up with a brand new telephone that can be used as a laser printer"

Comment: ISO stands for "in search of".  It isn't required here. Advertorial works for me, I saw an entire magazine full of them yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of hidden advertising is called ***commercial content***  or ***sponsored content***, also known as  ***native advertising*** .

> **Commercial content on the Guardian**
>
> Guardian News & Media produces a variety of content with funding from
> outside parties.

https://www.theguardian.com/info/2016/jan/25/content-funding

> **Native advertising** is a type of disguised advertising, usually online,
> that matches the form and function of the platform upon which it
> appears.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_advertising

---

If you're looking for a single word, you might use ***[advertorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advertorial)*** :

> an advertisement that imitates editorial format

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/advertorial

> a newspaper or magazine advertisement giving information about a
> product in the style of an editorial or objective journalistic
> article.
>
> ORIGIN 1960s (originally U.S.): blend of advertisement and
> editorial.

<sup>New Oxford American Dictionary</sup>

> **‘Advertorial’**
>
> Advertorial content describes features that are paid for and
> controlled by the advertiser rather than by The Australian; they are
> subject to regulation by the Advertising Standards Authority.

http://www.theaustralian.com.au/help/commercial-content-overview

Comment: You can turn the **sponsored content** into **sponsored news** :-)

Answer (score 2):

Contorting the information a bit to match the request for a single word, several terms are in play. The most common, and contemporary, jargon term is apparently 'native':

> **native advertising** Displaying an ad on a Web page along with regular content in a manner that does not distract the user. Contrast with "interrupt advertising," which requires users to cancel a message that demands their attention. See interstitial ad.

(*Computer Desktop Encyclopedia.* S.v. "native advertising." Retrieved September 14 2016 from http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/native+advertising.)

Another polite term, more likely to be familiar to others than those involved in the buying and selling of such quasi-news, is 'sponsored', as mentioned in this *Consumerist* story:

> Facebook began labeling certain shared links as “satire,” as a bit of hand-holding for its less-savvy users who can’t tell the difference between an actual news headline and one written by the writers of The Onion. But what Facebook really needs to do is start labeling so-called “native” or *sponsored* stories on non-satire sites....

(*Consumerist*, ["If Facebook Is Going To Label Satirical Stories, It Should Be Calling Out Ads Posing As News Links"](https://consumerist.com/2014/09/09/if-facebook-is-going-to-label-satirical-stories-it-should-be-calling-out-ads-posing-as-news-links/), Sept. 9, 2014. Emphasis mine.)

A less polite yet not downright disparaging term from earlier print and broadcast media, which may survive in some newsrooms but which has not, evidently, carried over to internet news sites, is 'phantom copy':

> “We used to call that ‘phantom copy’,” says Marquette University Professor Lawrence Soley. He has conducted several surveys measuring the pressures large advertisers put on print and broadcast newsrooms. “Essentially it’s a bonus ad,” he says. “Advertise with us and we’ll throw in phantom copy. It’s done very frequently by small weekly newspapers across the United States.”

(*Grade the News*, ["Advertising Disguised as News"](http://www.gradethenews.org/dreamhost%20files/pagesfolder/Advertising%20Disguised1.htm), undated.)

For even less polite terms, aside from 'quasi-news' (with the sense used in the foregoing answer), a discreet silence is perhaps best.

Comment: I've never (up to now) seen/heard "native" used in this sense.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this could fall under the definition of *clickbait*: online material (such as headlines) designed to make readers want to click on hyperlinks especially when the links lead to content of dubious value or interest. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clickbait

Comment: I presume OP is referring not only to online ads but offline ads too.

Comment: That's possible, but the way I read the original post it seemed like the OP was drawing a contrast between how this type of advertising used to be more readily identifiable as advertising in print and that the modern iteration on the Web is the misleading variety for which he is seeking a definition.